# Getting Image size in Javascript not working the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the image size using javascript, but it won't return the correct size until after I run it a second time.  I wonder why this is.  Here is my code:

```
   var img = new Image()
   img.src = src
   img.onLoad = alert(img.width);
```

This returns `0` sometimes, but after a couple times it returns the actual image width.  How do I make it get the right size the first time?  I thought this was the right way.

Comment: you need to put this code in on-load of page.

Comment: Please add the code. where you are calling the function from

Comment: You also must set `.onLoad` BEFORE you set `.src` or you will miss the `onload()` event in some circumstances in IE.

Comment: Yes, @Trevor gave the answer, I guess

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are calling alert directly instead of assigning it as a callback so it is called before the image is loaded. This is what you want to do:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    alert(img.width);
};
img.src = src;
```

Comment: You also need to put the `.onload` assignment before the `.src` assignment or it won't work properly in IE when the image is in the browser cache.

Comment: @jfriend00 Intresting, did not know that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
img.onload = function(){alert(img.width);}
```

instead of

```
img.onLoad = alert(img.width);
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer.  The original code was executing the `alert()` statement immediately and assigning its return value to `img.onload` which will obviously not do what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

found the code from this link:-

[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Use the clientWidth property of the image element.

```
img.clientWidth;
```

Comment: This has little to do with the actual issue.